# Quantum Regression Theorem Assumptions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions

The Quantum Regression Theorem states that if the time evolution of single-operator expectation values is known, then this determines the time evolution of higher-order correlations.Mathematically we can show that (See [Carmichael 1991](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-47620-7))

$\langle \dot{\textbf{A}}\rangle={\textbf{M}}\langle{\textbf{A}}\rangle$

where $\textbf{A}$ is the column vector of operators $ A_\mu$ and
expectation values$ \langle A_\mu \rangle$ for $\mu = 1,2, ...$,obey a coupled set of linear equations with the evolution matrix $\textbf{M}$ defined by the ${M}_{\mu \lambda}$.

$\langle \dot A_{\mu} \rangle=\sum_{\lambda} M_{\mu \lambda} \langle {A}_{\lambda} \rangle$

1. Are there any assumption or approximation in deriving it except being Markovian?
2. What does the matrix M physically represent? if possible a simple example about it.